# Efficient symmetric comparison based on a bool toggle

Tags: c++, c

my code has a lot of patterns like

```
int a, b.....
bool c = x ? a >= b : a <= b;
```

and similarly for other inequality comparison operators. Is there a way to write this to achieve better performance/branchlessness for x86.

Please spare me with `have you benchmarked your code? Is this really your bottleneck?` type comment. I am asking for other ways to write this so I can benchmark and test.

EDIT:

```
bool x
```

Comment: If you were switching between `<` and `>=` we could negate the result depending on `x`, such as `x != (a < b)`.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang: So `(a==b) || (c != (a<b))`?

Comment: Passing predicate template in C++ is a possibility.

Comment: @Jarod42 x is runtime variable.

Comment: Do you use same `x` for the whole function? Do you have several condition across the function?

Comment: I would guess that, with optimizations enabled, any other equivalent form of that expression will compile to the *exact same* assembly instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original expression:

```
x ? a >= b : a <= b
```

Branch-free equivalent expression without short-circuit evaluation:

```
!!x & a >= b | !x & a <= b
```

This is an example of a generic pattern without resorting to arithmetic trickery. Watch out for operator precedence; you may need parentheses for more complex examples.

Comment: indeed GCC doesn't put a branch back in the branchfree c code! not always the case

Comment: @leon The compiler is free to do what it likes of course, and it depends somewhat on the instruction set, but the branch free version has no *implied* branches at least! (Short-circuit `&&`, `||` and ternary `?:` imply branching, although the compiler might decide to avoid it if there are no side-effects.)

Comment: What is the advantage of `!!x` over plain `x` given that `x` is a `bool`?  Or was that not specified when you answered?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler in case original expression `x` is not bool, this convert it to bool in case there is `operator!` overload.

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be :

```
bool c = (2*x - 1) * (a - b) >= 0;
```

This generates a branch-less code here: https://godbolt.org/z/1nAp7G

```
#include <stdbool.h>
bool foo(int a, int b, bool x)
{
    return (2*x - 1) * (a - b) >= 0;
}
------------------------------------------
foo:
        movzx   edx, dl
        sub     edi, esi
        lea     eax, [rdx-1+rdx]
        imul    eax, edi
        not     eax
        shr     eax, 31
        ret
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you currently have it is possibly unbeatable.

But for positive integral `a` and `b` and `bool` `x` you can use

```
a / b * x + b / a * !x
```

(You could adapt this, at the cost of extra cpu burn, by replacing `a` with `a + 1` and similarly for `b` if you need to support zero.)

Comment: You expect 2 divisions & 2 multiplications to be faster?

Comment: Possible divide by zero.

Comment: @ScottHunter: Worth a go. This doesn't have any branches.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Fixed by moving the spec. (Come on, it's quite clever no ;-) )

Answer (score 1):

Since you're just looking for equivalent expressions, this comes from patching @AlexanderZhang's comment:

```
(a==b) || (c != (a<b))
```

Comment: `a<b` is not branchless on the current Intel chips. You can twiddle that though for integral `a` and `b`.

Comment: "I am asking for other ways to write this so I can benchmark and test."

Answer (score 0):

If a>=b, a-b will be positive and the first bit(sign bit) is 0. Otherwise a-b is negative and first bit is 1. 
So we can simply “xor” the first bit of a-b and the the value of x

```
constexpr auto shiftBit = sizeof(int)*8-1;
bool foo(bool x, int a, int b){
    return  x ^ bool((a-b)>>shiftBit);
}

foo(bool, int, int):
        sub     esi, edx
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     esi, 31
        xor     eax, esi
        ret
```